# Sort descending count column for same row of test

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I want to sort one column based on the other column.
I don't know how to do it in python using pandas.

Basically I want to suggest recommendation for the test column in descending order
This is what my data frame :

[image]]

This is what I tried to do.
Group by test column then sort on count column but it didn't work.

My Code   ::

```
final.groupby(['test'])
final.sort_values(['count'], ascending=False)
```

This is what i exactly want.
[image]

Comment: @Arman Yes Updated

Comment: @Arman its not allowing to embed images due to lack of reputation points. (Minimum 10)

Comment: @RohiniReddyCJ show your code as text.

Comment: @eyllanesc done!

Comment: `final.sort_values(['test','count'], ascending=[True,False])`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use sort_values:

```
final.assign(sortkey = df.test.apply(list).str[0])\
     .sort_values(by=['sortkey','count'], ascending=[True, False])\
     .drop('sortkey', axis=1)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'test':np.random.choice([{'Test1'},{'Test2'},{'Test3'}], 30),'count':np.random.randint(1000,5000, 30)})

df_out = df.assign(sortkey = df.test.apply(list).str[0])\
           .sort_values(by=['sortkey','count'], ascending=[True, False])\
           .drop('sortkey', axis=1)

df_out
```

Output:

```
    count     test
13   4121  {Test1}
23   2859  {Test1}
26   2125  {Test1}
0    1569  {Test1}
5    4620  {Test2}
27   4575  {Test2}
25   4336  {Test2}
22   3870  {Test2}
9    2460  {Test2}
17   2083  {Test2}
11   1689  {Test2}
24   1549  {Test2}
2    1093  {Test2}
4    4711  {Test3}
10   4536  {Test3}
12   4359  {Test3}
8    4288  {Test3}
18   4167  {Test3}
20   4085  {Test3}
15   3841  {Test3}
3    3379  {Test3}
7    3108  {Test3}
28   3027  {Test3}
21   2927  {Test3}
14   2491  {Test3}
1    2128  {Test3}
16   2114  {Test3}
19   2045  {Test3}
6    1927  {Test3}
29   1410  {Test3}
```

Comment: test column contains "set" thats why it is giving error that set is not hashable.

Comment: In my data frame Test1, Test2, Test3 rows repeats after some time.

Comment: It is now combining every row and disrupting the sequence

Comment: Create a dummy data set like i did in this solution and include the code in your question.  This will help with creating a good answer for you instead of using pictures your dataframe.